# How to solve Quartic Diophantine Equations

Tags: calculus, diophantine-equations

I have this diophantine equation:$$x^4 - 4 x^2 y - 66 x^2 + 1089 = 0$$Is there a way to find all integer $x$ values that make $y$ also an integer without factoring or checking $x$ values within a range?

Comment: What do you mean by 'solve this equation?'

Comment: Sorry, just realized I wasn't clear enough. Fixed it now.

Comment: HINT. You can treat this as a quadratic in $x^2$ and use the quadratic formula. It's not as bad as it looks. Note $33^2=1089$

Comment: I tried it but found out you have to factor. Also how would you use the quadratic formula with $4xy$ there?

Comment: @OldPeter How do I contine from here:$$\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{2*33}{4}+\frac{1}{x}\cdot\left(\frac{33^2}{4}\right)=y$$

Comment: It looks pretty easy but how do I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ x^4 - 4 x^2 y - 66 x^2 + 1089 = 0 $$
$$ x^4 - 2 (2 y + 33) x^2 + 1089 = 0 $$
$$ x^2 = 2 y + 33 +/- sqrt(4 y^2 + 132 y + 33^3 - 1089) $$
$$ x^2 = 2 y + 33 +/- sqrt(4 y^2 + 132 y) $$
$$ 4 y^2 + 132 y = M^2 $$
$$ (2y)^2 + 2 (2y) 33 - M^2 = 0 $$
$$ 2 y = - 33 +/- sqrt(1089 + M^2) $$
$$ 1089 + M^2 = W^2 $$
$$ (W-M) (W + M) = 1089 $$
$$ ... $$